# Owl Carousel doesent work on chrom on host

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have used owlCarousel in my project ,in a way that Special Products animate ,and in each slide 4 Products show,it worked correctly on my local but on host ,products are not animated but on other browsers they work correctly.even i have used special css for chrome that i have mentioned it in my post,but is not animating more.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        //nav: true,
        center: true,
        autoplay: true,

        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });

    $('.autoplay').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
    });

 
</script>
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
    .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        nav-right:initial;
        z-index: 1; /* added this */
    }

    .owl-item {
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    }

    </style>
```

```html
<link href="/lib/owlcarousel/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/owlcarousel/owl.transitions.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/lib/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
     <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme item-carousel" data-toggle="owlcarousel" data-owlcarousel-settings='{"items":4,  "navigation":true, "itemsScaleUp":true}'>
                    @Html.Action("ShowSpecialProducts", "Home")
                </div>
                
    <script src="/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<BehinFlex.Models.Products>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="overlay-wrapper">
            <img src="/ProductImages/Image/@item.ProductImageUrl" alt="ISOROLLS" class="img-responsive underlay" style="width:250px; height: 175px;">
            <span class="overlay">
                <span class="overlay-content"> <span class="h4">@item.ProductEnTitle </span> </span>
                @if (item.Discounts.Any())
                {
                    <span class="overlay-content">
                        <span>Discount:</span><span>%</span> @item.Discounts.FirstOrDefault().DiscountPercent.ToString("D")
                    </span>
                }
            </span>
        </a>

        <div class="item-details bg-noise">
            <h4 class="item-title">
                <a href="#">@item.ProductTitle</a>

            </h4>
            <a href="/Product/ShowProduct/@item.ProductID" class="btn btn-more i-right">more information<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: it can be because of your `href`s in loading the owl-carousel.  open your `console` in this page when your in host and see what are the errors.

Comment: thanks for replying, this is what i see in console      Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1119)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the lazy loading issue, that it wouldn't understand the image that had appeared on the screen, so I stopped lazy loading for carousel images.
I changed this:

`<img loading="lazy" src="image.jpg" alt="..." />`

to this:

`<img src="image.jpg" alt="..." />`